# how to open a link field in new window in view

Tags: views

In views,for image  field, I have selected "output this field as link" and in link path, I wrote "node/[nid]". Link works and open in same window. How to open the link in a new window? I dont see any option in view.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Click your image field at your views
2) Click Rewrite results. Check Output this field as a link. Key in your URL in the Link Path

[image]

) 3) At Target text field, key in this "_blank"

[image]

Comment: I glad it help. Do you mind give me vote up? Lol

Comment: I have the same problem but this solution does not work!! is there any other way?

Comment: May I know what you key in the link path and what is the option you choose for formatter?

Comment: my link path is the token of image field and formatter is just image

Comment: Similar approach on Drupal 8, where `[nid]` turns into `{{ nid }}`

Answer (score 1):

To do so programmatically, you need to define `ThemeName_preprocess_views_view_fields` function. Then in this function you should theme the views output. If the image field name is `field_image` then write:

```
function ThemeName_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables)
{
      $view = $variables['view'];
      if($view->name == "TheViewName")
      {
           $variables['image'] = $variables['fields']['field_image']->FIND THE IMAGE PATH BY DEVEL MODULE;
           $variables['link'] =  $variables['fields']['field_image']->FIND THE IMAGE LINK ADDRESS BY DEVEL MODULE;  
      }
}
```

Then create `views-view-fields--TheViewName--DisplayNameOfView.tpl` file and in this file write

```
$image = strip_tags($image) ;
<a href="<?php print $link?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php print $image;?>"</a>
```

Notice that you should install [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module to get required information about the image, its link and etc.

Clearly in this method you will have more choices of displaying the link and you can also use this method to open the image in a popup window.

This is the main idea of doing this and I always use this. I didn't test this code but a few modification might be needed. for example in  `views-view-fields--TheViewName--DisplayNameOfView.tpl` you can use `<?php print $fields['field_image']->content; ?>` to output the entire linked image.